# Trying to get MFT table from Python 3

Tags: python, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I try to read MFT table from my local disk from python. Of course, if I write something like this:

```
input_file = open('C:\$MFT', "rb")
```

I will get

> [ Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\$MFT'

I tried to use pyMFTGrabber, but it doesn't work; I got a lot of "socket.errors".

What the best and easy way to read this file, using Python? 
Maybe it is some WinAPI, or something else?
After reading I want to analyze it with `"analyzeMFT"`

Comment: Try executing this program with Administrator rights?

Comment: Yes, I execute it as Admin)

Answer (score 1):

It's rather painful with python, since it's not exactly low-level.

I think you should start with this though:

`L"\\\\?\\C:\\$MFT"`
is the namespace you need to use in MS's VC++ API in order to create a handle to the MFT.

You should consider looking through the source code of the grabber you mentioned [pyMFTGrabber](https://github.com/jeffbryner/pyMFTGrabber/blob/master/pyMFTGrabber.py) and scroll down to the bottom and it shows you how the author accessed the file (it looks accurate - reads sectors instead of trying to directly access `$MFT`, and it looks pretty well commented too). If you read the details of the project, it says that it is a 'Script to retrieve the Master File Table (MFT) record for an NTFS file system from a live system.'

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, other options emerged: There's a library to analyze the  Master File Table ($MFT) from an NTFS file system called [analyzeMFT](https://github.com/dkovar/analyzeMFT).

> analyzeMFT.py is designed to fully parse the MFT file from an NTFS
>   filesystem and present the results as accurately as possible in
>   multiple formats.

To get it use [pip](https://pypi.org/project/analyzeMFT/)  (current version 2.0.19) or install it from the source found on [GitHub](https://github.com/dkovar/analyzeMFT)

```
pip install analyzeMFT
```

Comment: @user2319786  Or, for what's worth it, you can take a look at the code and see how it's done.