# How do I access NTFS Master File Table (MFT)?

Tags: javascript, python, ntfs

Is there any way I can access NTFS Master File Table (MFT) in Python or JavaScript?

Comment: Duplicate apparently: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25370809/131187.

Comment: Would you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a library to analyze the  Master File Table ($MFT) from a NTFS file system.

For Python there is [analyzeMFT](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/analyzeMFT/2.0.19) (current version 2.0.19) on pip.

> analyzeMFT.py is designed to fully parse the MFT file from an NTFS
>   filesystem and present the results as accurately as possible in
>   multiple formats.

```
pip install analyzeMFT
```

For JavaScript I cannot tell exactly, but I suppose you can use this node.js [ntfs](https://github.com/jhermsmeier/node-ntfs) package to read & parse the NTFS $MFT.

```
$ npm install --save ntfs
```